# Arduino - Push Button State Problem

Tags: arduino-yun, button, buzzer

My problem is I want the buzzer to stop after a certain amount of time, regardless if it is still pressed or not.

I have tried to implement a boolean statement to the code but to no avail(I'm not very good at this)

Can someone shed some light as to how I do this?

The code already times out after 1000ms when your finger is lifted off the buttin so I got that far but cant get any further.

Here is what I have.

Any other suggestions are also welcome as I know its not the prettiest or best implemented but i was just happy it worked for me.

```
// Setting The Pin Numbers
const int touchsensor = 2;                      // the number of the touchsensor pin
const int buzzer =  4;                          // the number of the LED pin

// variables:
int touchsensorState = 0;                       // variable for reading the 
touchsensor status
unsigned long timestamp = 0;
unsigned long timeout = 1000;

void setup() {

  pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);                      // initialize the buzzer as an output
  pinMode(touchsensor, INPUT);                  // initialize the touchsensor as an input
 }
void loop() {

   touchsensorState = digitalRead(touchsensor);  // read state of the pushbutton value:

   if (touchsensorState == HIGH) {                 // check if the touch sensor is pressed. If it is, the touchsensorState is HIGH:
     digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH);                 // buzzer will emit sound:
     timestamp = millis();                       // Timing button press
   } 

   if(millis() - timestamp > timeout) {
   digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);                  // buzzer will not sound:
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you will need to implement a edge sensor. Add a `previousTouchsensorState` to the globals and replace the if where you check the sensor state with:

```
if(previousTouchsensorState == LOW && touchsensorState == HIGH) {                 
     // check if the touch sensor is pressed and wasn't the last time though the loop. 
     // If it is, the touchsensorState is HIGH and previousTouchsensorState is LOW:
     digitalWrite(buzzer, HIGH); // buzzer will emit sound:
     timestamp = millis();       // Timing button press
}
previousTouchsensorState  = touchsensorState;
```